# move the text downwards using css and setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css

using CSS and setinterval, I need to move the text downwards with a "start" button. 
suppose, there is a text box and when I press the start button the text should move downwards and when I press stop button, it should stop the text motion.

```
<style>
.class1{ 
    position: relative; 
    padding-top: 10px; 
}
<body> 
    <p input id="para">Paragraph</p> 
    <button id="srt" onclick="start()" >Start</button> 
    <button id="stp" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
    <script> 
        var i=document.getElementById("para"); 
        setInterval(function start(){ 
            i.className="class1"; 
        },1000) 
    </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: try adding some javascript with a setinterval call. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial site.

Comment: Edit the question and add your code there.

Comment: [requestAnimationFrame](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/) > `setInterval` all day every day..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude solution that uses `setInterval` and CSS to create an animation:

```js
let intervalId;

const increaseMarginTop = () => {
  const el = document.querySelector('#targetEl');
  const currentMarginTop = Number(el.style.marginTop.substring(0, el.style.marginTop.length - 2)) + 1;

  el.style.marginTop = `${currentMarginTop}px`;
};

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    if (e.target.id === 'stp') {
      intervalId = clearInterval(intervalId);
    } else if (e.target.id === 'srt') {
      if (!intervalId) {
        intervalId = setInterval(increaseMarginTop, 10);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="srt">Start</button>
<button id="stp">Stop</button>

<div id="targetEl">This will move down</div>
```

[Just FYI - there are better ways to do animations in modern JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).